# how to change the content of listview according to the clicked item?

Tags: java, android

Having an listview,if i clicked an item in the listview it has to go to the same activity for all item clicking in an list view,what i need is the same activity has to display the contents as different one according to their respective click item.
I am having doubt in that activity how to create that one for respective clicking and fetches their data

```
 public class SouthIndianvegrecipes1  extends Activity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                    Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                    Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class);     
                                startActivity(newActivity);
                    /*switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                    {
                        case 1:
                             Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                            SouthIndianvegrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(newActivity);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                    SouthIndiannonvegrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(new1Activity);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                    SouthIndianpickelsrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(new2Activity);
                            break; 

                        case 4:
                            Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                    SouthIndiansoupsrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(new3Activity);
                            break;      

                       default:
                           Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }*/
                     /*if(obj_itemDetails.getName().equals("Vegeterain"))
                     {

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                                     SouthIndianvegrecipes.class);     
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                     }

                     else
                       {
                        Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                SouthIndiannonvegrecipes.class);     
                        startActivity(new1Activity);

                     //same for other Activity
                  } */
                } 
            });
        }

        private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
            ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

            Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Godhumai veg adai");
            item_details.setItemDescription("This is very good for dibets people");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(12);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Soyamore koozh");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Tasty to have this as main dish");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(13);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Tomato kulambu");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(14);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Tomato upma");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Evening time  dinner for kids");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(15);
            results.add(item_details);


            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Tomato upma");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Evening time  dinner for kids");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(15);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Navratri special vada");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Good snacks at the function");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(16);
            results.add(item_details);


            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Egg kurma");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Wonderful dish made by egg");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(17);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Milagu kuzhambu");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Good for digestion purpose");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(18);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Rasam");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Last and famous dish in lunch,good for health also");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(19);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Vegetable kootu");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Nice and healthy one");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(20);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("Avial");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Easy to prepare and lots of vegetable");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(21);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails();
            item_details.setName("kothavarangaicurry");
            item_details.setItemDescription("Tamilnadu special and healthy too");
            //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber(22);
            results.add(item_details);


            return results;
        }
```

}this is code,here if i click that item in an listview,it has to go the next activity and where i will write the data for items

```
 public class SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes  extends Activity {

         private Object getIntent;

        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.recipe_manual);

                ArrayList<Recipedetails2> image_details = GetSearchResults();

                final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
                lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter2(this, image_details));

               /* lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                        Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                        Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                    SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class);     
                                    startActivity(newActivity);
                        /*switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                        {
                            case 1:
                                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                               SouthIndianvegrecipes.class);     
                               startActivity(newActivity);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                        SouthIndiannonvegrecipes.class);     
                                startActivity(new1Activity);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                        SouthIndianpickelsrecipes.class);     
                                startActivity(new2Activity);
                                break; 

                            case 4:
                                Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                                        SouthIndiansoupsrecipes.class);     
                                startActivity(new3Activity);
                                break;      

                           default:
                               Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }*/
                         /*if(obj_itemDetails.getName().equals("Vegeterain"))
                         {

                            Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                                         SouthIndianvegrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(newActivity);
                         }

                         else
                           {
                            Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                    SouthIndiannonvegrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(new1Activity);

                         //same for other Activity
                      } */
                    //} 
                //});
            }
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int[] obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber() = extras.getIntArray("numbers");

            private ArrayList<Recipedetails2> GetSearchResults(){
                ArrayList<Recipedetails2> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails2>();

                Recipedetails2 item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Godhumai veg adai");
                item_details.setIngredients("This is very good for dibets people");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(12);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Soyamore koozh");
                item_details.setIngredients("Tasty to have this as main dish");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(13);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Tomato kulambu");
                item_details.setIngredients("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(14);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Tomato upma");
                item_details.setIngredients("Evening time  dinner for kids");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(15);
                results.add(item_details);


                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Tomato upma");
                item_details.setIngredients("Evening time  dinner for kids");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(15);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Navratri special vada");
                item_details.setIngredients("Good snacks at the function");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(16);
                results.add(item_details);


                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Egg kurma");
                item_details.setIngredients("Wonderful dish made by egg");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(17);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Milagu kuzhambu");
                item_details.setIngredients("Good for digestion purpose");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(18);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Rasam");
                item_details.setIngredients("Last and famous dish in lunch,good for health also");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(19);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Vegetable kootu");
                item_details.setIngredients("Nice and healthy one");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(20);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("Avial");
                item_details.setIngredients("Easy to prepare and lots of vegetable");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(21);
                results.add(item_details);

                item_details = new Recipedetails2();
                item_details.setName("kothavarangaicurry");
                item_details.setIngredients("Tamilnadu special and healthy too");
                item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
                //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
                item_details.setImageNumber(22);
                results.add(item_details);


                return results;
            }

    }
```

here how i wil write the  code for taking the data 
my xml file,i want to put the code here like respective click

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:orientation="vertical"

  >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemphoto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
  ></ImageView>

  <TextView
      android:text="Ingredients:"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/itemIngredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center" />

   <TextView
      android:text="Method:"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/methods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. Are you having trouble passing information to the activity you're launching (in which case intent extras are likely what you're looking for)?

Comment: i have 7 items in an listview,whether all the 7 items clicking has to go the same activity,but according to their clicking it has to change their date alone,but layout is same,date is image text and their description,it has to change according to their click

Comment: You want to put the information in your Intent when you construct it. Read the relevant [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), paying special attention to the part about extras (where you can put custom bits of information for your activity to retrieve in `onCreate` or another lifecycle method).

Answer (score 1):

You can change date according to the position or name of ListView item.Suppose

```
String name[]={"a","b","c","d"};
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                   String current=name[position];

//now put condition here to start different activity

if(current.equals("a"))
{
//do operation what u have to do for a
}else if(current.equals("b"))
{
//do operation what u have to do for b
}
similarly put here condition for all
        });
```

Good luck enjoy

Comment: now i will paste my code,in that code,if i mention the activity,in that activity how i will put the data of different items and how to fetch it according to their click

Comment: acually if u click on a list then current will have a value so u can operate according to this.

Comment: ya but what i need is,if i click the first item in an list view,it has to show their 2 item data in the next activity,

Comment: you must describe exactly what u have to do...if this then get listdate and use intent.putextra for this

Comment: i given one acitiviy here thats the first list activity ok,if i click all item in an listactivity,it will go to the second activity,what i need is the second activity having datas according to their first list activity,if i click the 3 item in an first list,the second activity correctly fetches the 3 items data in an second activity and has to display

Comment: is this possible to send the parameter to one activity to another one actually what i am thinking is if we pass the clicking activity to another name,we can match it and get their data

Comment: yeah possible useing Intent intent=new Intent(this,activityname.class);
intent.putextra("a",valuethatuwannapass);
StartActivity(intent).And using get extra u can get value.Like String value =getIntent.getextra.getstring("a"); good luck

Comment: can you tell me  hot to get the obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber() from using this Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                            SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class);     
                            startActivity(newActivity);

Comment: it's easy dear,just use putextra and using position of listview u can get..just think

Comment: ya i put like this  newActivity.putExtra("numbers", obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber()); ,its not showing any error but in the next activity how i can compare these number and that number and hot to fetch that data and display it

Comment: I already said this...here you need to use getExtra(). String value =getIntent.getextra.getstring("numbers")

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KmJvsjyj this is that second activity code,how to compare that number with this activity number ,after comparison how to take the data and display it

Comment: how to give the data according to their respective click in the second activity,see my second activity in the above link and tell me

Comment: can you see my code at the second activitgy hot to compare and fetch that respective data to display

Comment: if i click the first item named as Godhumai veg adai in the list,it has to display what are the things same in the second activity  named as Godhumai veg adai,that thing should be display

Comment: so it's Simple,fetch listView clicked item name(which i have maintained above in my answer)send it to another activity using putextra(),in second activity get data using getextras() and then display where u want display

Comment: Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                             SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class );    
            newActivity.putExtra("numbers", obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber());
                             startActivity(newActivity);its in first activity and the second activity is  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 int arrayB = extras.getInt("numbers"); this is correct ?

Comment: in 2nd activity use only String value =getIntent.getextra.getstring("numbers");

Comment: it will show error in getextra cannot resolve or is not a field they are mentioning,if i tell preiously some code,its shows error in logcat only then only i can use switch case]

Comment: which types of value u r passing u need to pass string so u can get string ...and plz post logcat too

Comment: showing null pointer so check yr data is being passes successfully or not logic and code is right but u r not passing data or may be object is not being instantiate properly so check

Comment: ent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                             SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class );    
            newActivity.putExtra("numbers", obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber());
                             startActivity(newActivity);---first activity and Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray("numbers");--second activity and you can check my remaining code,

Comment: my full activity can you see and tell

Comment: it's looking fine code,now do one thing use breakpoint and run app in debug mode so u can debug it easily